# How to compare EST date time with mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have purchase data in mysql database table. All data on server are stored in UTC timezone.

I can convert date-time in EST timezone using below code.

```
$date = date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), timezone_open('Etc/GMT+0'));
date_timezone_set($date, timezone_open('Etc/GMT+5'));
```

I am getting last and next Saturday of current day using below code.

```
$dt_week_start_time = strtotime("last saturday")+((20*3600)+ 1);
$dt_week_start_date = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', $dt_week_start_time);

$dt_week_end_time = $dt_week_start_time + (7*3600*24) - 1;
$dt_week_end_date = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', $dt_week_end_time);
```

But how can i compare above EST timezone converted date-time with mysql data stored in UTC timezone? I need to convert data of 'purchasedatetime' field in EST timezone when I fire below query. Is this possible? Or am I doing it in wrong way? Please advise.

```
$str_query_select = "SELECT *, SUM(extendedprice) AS gross_price FROM t_product_purchase ";
$str_query_select .= " WHERE purchasedatetime BETWEEN '".$dt_week_start_date ."' AND '".$dt_week_end_date."'";
$str_query_select .= " AND sellerpkid=1";
$str_query_select .= " GROUP BY purchasedatetime ORDER BY purchasedatetime DESC ";
```

Comment: you can convert the time zone using convert_tz() of mysql.visit here http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14062

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

or

```
SET time_zone = 'proper timezone';
being done once right after connect to database. and after this all timestamps will be converted automatically when selecting them.
```

in php you can do this:

$date = new DateTime($dt_week_start_date);
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow')); // based on your required zone

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

then use it in your sql.

Comment: $str_query_select = "SELECT CONVERT_TZ(purchasedatetime, 'UTC', 'EST' ) FROM t_product_purchase"; ... this query giving this error 'Notice: Undefined index: purchasedatetime' Please advise what is wrong with this query?

Comment: you have to write something like this:$str_query_select = "SELECT CONVERT_TZ((select purchasedatetime from t_product_purchase), 'UTC', 'EST' ) FROM t_product_purchase.in your query for your conversion there is no purchasedatetime defined to convert i.e. why you are getting this notice.i'll suggest better change in your configuration.